# Stacks and queues are giving errors in Dev-C++

Tags: c++

I was given and assignment to develop a cellphone simulation, part of the requirements includes me using a queue to store the phone numbers that come from a txt file to simulate getting called. I have reviewed over and over again and including #include but the error message telling me "Queue" undeclared still shows up. I am using Bloodsehd Dev-C++, and I have included a sample I used to test the queue, if it is just the program not having the right information, any help would be appreciated.  I have checked other sites most say add a #include  or a #include neither seemed to solve the problem.

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class cell
{
    public:
        cell();
        ~cell();
        void upload( string item );//Insert in order
        void printnew();//Print call just recieved
        void printlater();//Print calls for later
        int Front(); //returns front element
        int Rear(); //returns rear element
        bool Empty();

    private:


};

int main()
{
    Queue Q;
    Q.Enqueue(54);
    cout << Q.front();


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Queue" isn't the same thing as "queue"... Try queue<int> Q

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

queue is supposed to be lowercase.

You can find info on using the queue here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/queue/

Comment: Thank you Nik and user, seems this handout the teacher gave us is no use.  If the info on the sheet does not work like it is written then were we set up to fail.

Answer (score 2):

To use STL queue, you need to:

```
#include <queue>     // include necessary header

std::queue<int> q;   // initialize queue container with type int
q.push(54);          // add element to queue
std::cout << q.front() << std::endl; // access the head of queue
```

checkout `std::queue` reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use C++ Standard Library [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/), you must declare it as

```
queue<int> Q;
Q.push(54);
cout << Q.front();
```

Comment: Thank you as well, this info will defiantly help since nothing on the handout works.

Comment: queue has no push_back member

Comment: @billz Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Comment: Yes, I have just tested push and it works just as I need it.  The sheet the teacher passed out said to use Q.Enqueue, push was used in the stack section.  But I should be able to write my program using this info.